# Existe uma forma de filtrar os contatos por "organização" na agenda de contatos do Android, quando acionada através de outra atividade?

Tags: java, android, intent

Em uma aplicação para Android, pretendo abrir a agenda de contatos a partir de outra `Activity` via `Intent`, mas gostaria que aparecessem apenas os contatos que trazem um valor específico no campo "Organização". Existe uma forma de especificar isso no `Intent` que abre a agenda de contatos? Segue o código atual, no qual o `Intent` é iniciado ao clicar do botão `getContactDetails`:

```
getContactDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Inicia atividade de lista de contatos, para obter os dados do contato
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                   ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Exatamente isso você pode fazer como é feito a operação em um banco de dados qualquer no android.

```
String[] projection = new String[]{Calls.NUMBER, Calls.DURATION};
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Calls.DATE +" desc");
```

No exemplo acima estou pegando no meu caso as ligações, como precisa dos contatos basta trocar  algo como:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Claudsan, entendo que a query vai me retornar os resultados filtrados, porém isso vai me mostrar apenas os contatos selecionados no próprio aplicativo de contatos default do Android? Imagino que seja necessário um `Intent` pra isso, não?

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim ,aqui tem um exemplo mais detalhado você pode ordernar por qualquer campo que queira

https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html

Abaixo trecho extraído direto da documentação citado acima.

**Define a sort order**

Define a sort order for the returned Cursor. Since you're retrieving a specific data type, omit the sort on MIMETYPE. Instead, if the type of detail data you're searching includes a subtype, sort on it. For example, for email data you can sort on Email.TYPE:

```
private static final String SORT_ORDER = Email.TYPE + " ASC ";
```

Comment: @clausdan, mas esse esquema seria para obter os dados em uma lista, não? O que eu quero não são puramente os dados filtrados (resultado de uma query), pretendo é usar a própria atividade de agenda de contatos mostrando apenas os contatos de uma dada empresa, por exemplo, sendo retornado unicamente o contato que o usuário selecionar (no caso por meio da callback `onActivityResult`).